# Searching synonyms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create synonym search over languages indexed in ES.

For example,

Indexed document -> name: German

Synonyms: German, Deutsch, XYZ

What I want to make is, when I type either German or Deutsch or XYZ, that ES returns me German...

Is that possible at all?

Comment: yes, of course http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes very much so. ElasticSearch handles synonyms very well. Here is an example of how I configured synonyms on my cluster -

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/**new-index** -d '{
"settings": {
"number_of_shards": 2,
"number_of_replicas": 0,
"analysis": {
  "filter": {
    "synonym": {
      "type": "synonym",
      "synonyms_path": "synonyms/synonyms.txt"
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "synonym": {
      "tokenizer": "lowercase",
      "filter": [
        "synonym"
      ]
    }
  }
 }
},
"mappings": {
"**new-type**": {
  "_all": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "properties": {
    "Title": {
      "type": "multi_field",
      "store": "yes",
      "fields": {
        "Title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "synonym"
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}'
```

The path for the synonym file looks inside the **config** folder for the synonym folder and locates the text file. An example of the contents of the synonyms.txt for your requirements would be -

German, Deutsch, XYZ

**REMEMBER** - if you have a lower case filter at index time, the synonyms need to be in lower case. Restart nodes if not working.